# Having two VirtualBox VMs with NAT but different IP from host?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, nat

I have two Linux VMs `A` and `B` in VirtualBox 6.1 (Host: Windows 10).

I am using `NAT` Network Mode for both machines.
I am currently able to connect with `ssh root@127.0.1.1` to the machine `A` (from the host).

When I start the second machine `B`, I would likeconnect to `B` by e.g. `ssh root@127.0.1.2`.
But the second machine also uses the external ip `127.0.1.1`.

How can I changes this such that both machines are accessible from the host with two different ips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have `A.vbox` with the following entries:

```xml
<Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="08002731CD46" type="82540EM">
          <NAT>
            <Forwarding name="ssh" proto="1" hostip="127.0.1.1" hostport="22" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="22"/>
          </NAT>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
```

And the other `B.vbox` file with

```xml
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="08002761CE67" type="82540EM">
          <NAT>
            <Forwarding name="ssh" proto="1" hostip="127.0.1.2" hostport="22" guestip="10.0.2.15" guestport="22"/>
          </NAT>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
```

Answer (score 0):

The VirtualBox and VMware can support different types of connection with your host. And since you choose NAT mode, actually there is a virtual NIC and a local ip like 192.168.0.1 or else, you can use it. What's more, both of the two apps support setting IP address by yourself. So it seems not very hard to solve.